# self join return wrong value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, self-join

i have this users table

```
|id|name|parent_id|
|1 |   A|2        |
|2 |   B|null     |
|3 |   C|1        |
```

when i query using this statement
`select  u.id, u.name, p.parent from users u left join users p on p.parent_id = u.id;`
i want it return table like this,

```
|id|name|parent|
|1 |   A|B     |
|2 |   B|null  |
|3 |   C|A     |
```

,it give me wrong value.

```
|id|name|parent|
|1 |   A|C     |
|2 |   B|A     |
|3 |   C|null  |
```

how to fix it and why it give me wrong table?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i made a table with following entries :

```
postgres=# select * from users order by id;
 id | name | parent_id 
----+------+-----------
  1 | A    |         2
  2 | B    |          
  3 | C    |         1
(3 rows)
```

and output of following query is

```
postgres=# select  u.id,u.name,p.name as parent  from users u left join users p on u.id=p.parent_id;
 id | name | parent 
----+------+--------
  1 | A    | C
  2 | B    | A
  3 | C    |
```

and output of following query with some different join(**comapre left table parent id with right table id to get your desired result**) is :

```
postgres=# select  u.id,u.name,p.name as parent  from users u left join users p on u.parent_id=p.id order by u.id;
 id | name | parent 
----+------+--------
  1 | A    | B
  2 | B    | 
  3 | C    | A
(3 rows)
```

One other way to achieve this is as follows :

```
postgres=# select  p.id,p.name,u.name as parent  from users u right join users p on u.id=p.parent_id order by p.id;
 id | name | parent 
----+------+--------
  1 | A    | B
  2 | B    | 
  3 | C    | A
(3 rows)
```

In above query i made right join instead of left beacuse all over you want to     do is very important which is  **match parent id with id not id with parent id**

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

i think your query is wrong, it should be `select  u.id, u.name, p.parent from users u left join users p on u.parent_id = p.id;`
the condition of the join is wrong